# Is there a control to visualize mesh topology in c#?

Tags: c#, data-visualization

Does anyone know of a c# tool to visualize interconnected nodes (e.g. the call hierarchy in a class)? The sort of visualization I'm looking for is like that of the ANTS Memory Profiler when it's showing memory links if anyone is familiar with that tool?

Comment: Well, in ANTS it's just a tree, right? Do you want this for web or WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool that I've found is Graph# found at http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/. It seems to work brilliantly for plotting the kind of nodal interdependencies I'm after.

Apologies to those who I mislead with the ANTS reference. If it's any consolation, NDepend looks a seriously interesting tool.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at NDepend (http://www.ndepend.com/). In addition to computing various metrics for a code base, it can also visualize dependencies. A trial edition is available.

Here is a screenshot (on http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#DependenciesView) that may be what you're looking for: http://www.ndepend.com/Res/DiagramBoxAndArrowGraphBig.jpg

Answer (score 3):

To complete Matthew's answer on NDepend, have a look at these 2 articles concerning NDepend dependency graph and NDepend dependency matrix. Graph and Matrix work hands in hands.

- [Dependency Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx) : Graph is more intuitive but hard to understand when there are more than 30 nodes.
- [Dependency Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx) : Matrix is less intuitive than Graph, but it scales, meaning, it can still be useful even with hundreds of nodes shown.

Here are 2 screenshots:

[image]
[image]